# What is the filter and the transfer function that shown below?

Tags: filter

[image]

May i know above is below to which type of filter?
is it a low pass filter?
and what is the transfer function for the circuit, may i know the step to drive it?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on values as to how you might regard its operation.

Comment: If you are unsure, its easiest to simulate it in something like LTspice and look at the results.

Comment: But such a simulation gives not the transfer function.

Comment: @LvW, do an `.AC` anaylysis.

Comment: Jasen-I am not the questioner; and I repeat: An ac analysis does not give the FUNCTION. Such an analysis shows the frequency response only.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think someone will post you the answer, but to put you in the good track, you just use the Fourrier Transform for the impedance because clearly we ar interested in RSP and not transient than just use what you know about op amp, V- = V + = 0 , find the current in Cin - Rin than you can find the Vout and than find the transfer function

Plus, quickly i can say that for DC, it just an inverter amp-op and for the rest of frequency, it is a bandpass filter , but I am not quite sure because Cin and Rin are in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Why not finding the transfer function? Knowing the principle of an inverting opamp with resistive feedback it should not be a big problem to replace the resistors R2 and R1 by the corresponding complex terms Z2 and Z1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a PID Regulator. The P part is given by RIn and RF2 the I part by RIn and the integrator part RF1 and CF and last but not least the D part from CIn, RIn and RF2. Simulating or write down the frequnce response locus or nyquist plot should lead a good image of the circuit.

P.S: Nobody uses this today like this ;-)